# Number encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, number-theory

I have a list of numbers. I will be calling a service(let's say accountant service) which is going to perform some operation on these list of numbers and will return me the final result number.

I don't want to pass my data in plain format. I want to encrypt numbers in such a way if service performs any arithmetic operation and return me the result, I will be able to decrypt it back with actual result.

Comment: Seems like a great usecase for chunked (block cipher) symmetric encryption to me

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a combination of [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) and [verifiable computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_computing).

Homomorphic encryption plays a part in this, but it is possibly not the only tool that you need. Homomorphic encryption can preserve the confidentiality of your values, but it cannot ensure that the computation was performed as you specified. That is what verifiable computation does.

Depending on the nature of the operations that you need to perform, you may not require fully homomorphic encryption. If you only require the ability to add ciphertexts together, and you don't care about post-quantum resistance, then the [Paillier cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) is an option for you. It's not standardized to my knowledge, but it's older and has been used in other projects.

Otherwise, if you really want/need a standardized homomorphic encryption algorithm, you might opt to use one of the submissions that were recently [submitted to NIST](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/post-quantum-cryptography/round-1-submissions). These algorithms are not standardized yet, but they are on track to be, assuming that they are not broken before then. Many of them are based on lattice problems, which implies that may offer homomorphic encryption.

While verifiable computation doesn't have a standardized solution yet (that I am aware of), there has been work into implementing it: See [Pinocchio](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/279.pdf) and [Pepper](https://www.pepper-project.org).

Comment: Verifiable computation does not provide confidentiality.

Comment: I don't think any Homomorphic encryption standard is available ?

Comment: Linking to a PQ cipher and key exchange competition when talking about standardized HE is confusing. Sure, much math is shared (RLWE for example) between solutions of these two problems but the aim aren't always overlapping.